# why are simple organic molecules usually white?

Tags: color

I have heard that it is because they absorb electronically in the ultraviolet range, if this is true, why is it true. What is it about the nature of organic molecules that make them absorb in the ultraviolet range.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is snow white?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/26749/why-is-snow-white)

Comment: nah, i don't think this is a duplicate. I'm pretty sure that snow is white for a different reason.

Comment: Everything is white when it doesn't absorb or disperse visible light but is scattering it.

Comment: IMHO the question is **not** a duplicate, but its answer is. Indeed, snow is white for pretty much the same reason.

Comment: If it's already answered, it is a dupe, **but** there is another mechanism, indeed involving absorption of UV - fluorescence, you could modify your quesrion, so it wouldn't get closed

Comment: @Mithoron It is only a duplicate if **the question** is the same.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Yes, but if answer is appropriate on many questions, it determines level of similarity needed to treat them as dupes.

Comment: @Mithoron It really does not. Closing a question as duplicate is pretty straight forward and it only concerns the question. If the answer on two different questions would be the same, then the questions are still not, they are related. Even if the answer goes as far as explaining the question, too, then the questions are still different. On first sight, small organic molecules and snow don't have much in common. I would be really confused if one question leads to the answer of another that seems completely unrelated.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Looks like another theory vs practice problem...

Answer (score 7):

Most substances are white in powder form if they have no strong absorption of visible light. They whiteness is a consequence of light scattering by small particles *and* the fact that there is no absorption within the visible range.

The lack of visible absorption is another issue. Light is absorbed by molecules when the energy difference between a filled orbital and an unfilled one in the molecule matches the energy of a photon of light. For light photons the energy is the equivalent of wavelength and therefore colour.

In most small, simple organic molecules, the lowest unfilled orbitals are a long way from the highest filled ones. So they need a lot of energy to cause them to jump to an unfilled orbital. So they absorb only high energy photons (UV light is higher energy than visible light so this implies the absorption bands will be in the UV and we will not notice them as our eyes can't see UV).

The characteristics that create colour in molecules are often long runs of unsaturated bonds where the electrons can spread along the chain of unsaturation. In these delocalised systems the gap between occupied and unoccupied orbitals is smaller than in simpler molecules and often falls into the visible spectrum. These molecules are perceived as coloured.

The molecule below is a simple example of a dye (most are bigger and more complex than this):

[image: acid red 74 structure]

The electrons in this molecule can delocalise over all three rings via the NN bridge and this creates orbitals with the right energy gap to absorb blue light.

In simpler molecules with little delocalisation the energy gap is far into the UV. Even in polycyclic aromatic systems the energy gap is often still in the UV.

Of course, this is a simplification, but the essence of what sort of molecules you need to cause visible colour is a relatively large unsaturated system and by definition this doesn't happen in very simple organic molecules. [Wikipedia](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Dye) lists many more examples of dyes so you can get a feel for what sorts of structures make strongly coloured compounds.